# GCP Cost billing data

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-cloud-platform

I am new to GCP and its cloud services offered. For a real-time cost analysis project, what is the best approach to get day-to-day billing reports just like Azure [ Cost Management report ], and AWS [ billing report ]. I have researched few methods using BigQuery however, that seem to be feasible given the administrative constraints regarding the client policy to share account details.

Please should an alternative approach to extract cost reports ? I'm open to explore APIs is available.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you meaning to install `pip install --upgrade google-cloud-billing`? You want to use [Cloud Billing API](https://cloud.google.com/billing/v1/getting-started)? I am not familiar with AWS or Azure Reports. Is any of [Budget Api Examples](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/budget-api) is what you need?

Answer (score 3):

There is no Python package published by Google to display billing data. Google Cloud does not provide APIs that directly access billing details.

Google Cloud's method of accessing billing data is to export the billing data to BigQuery and then query BigQuery for billing details. Billing data is then available after the export is enabled. Previous billing data is not available.

[Python Client for Google BigQuery](https://googleapis.dev/python/bigquery/latest/index.html)

[Export Cloud Billing data to BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/export-data-bigquery)

To generate your own reports programmatically requires interfacing with BigQuery to query your billing data. Your software then tabulates the data for display.